# My selenium session doesn't get the right cookies

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies

I have my selenium script running in aws lambda.
The thing is that I have this webpage where I have to login to access to the required data and all the process work, but not always, I mean selenium pass the password and the username, click in the button to login and the driver should access to the required page, but this don't happend always, I print the driver's cookies and when the login work right, there are 20 cookies, but when it doesn't, have only 3 cookies.
Other thing related to my problem is that if I do something like this.

Dummy example:

```
def my_lambda_handler(event, context):
"""
all my selenium process
"""
try:
    #some code
except Exception as e:
    driver.quit
    return {}

data = my_lambda_handler(
    event={the data of my event},
    context={}
)

while data == {}:
    data = my_lambda_handler(
    event={the data of my event},
    context={}
    )

print(data)
```

So, when I use this while loop, I always have the correct data at the first try of the while loop. but if I try the login with in the lambda handler instead of calling the lambda handler as I do in the while loop, it doesn't work.

This are my webdriver option (chrome)

```
options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/tmp")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```